# Azure cognitive stops immediately after I start

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to transcribe a WAV file and return the text, but it stopped immediately when I start working

I have a button, that when I click it, will call this method, and it supposedly returns me the text of the wav file, but as you can see from the code, I have a Dbug.WriteLine in the start and the stop, and it will print stop immediately

```
   public List<char> Letters { get; set; }

    public StringBuilder Builder { get; set; }

    public AzureTranscriptionService() {

        Letters = new List<char>();
        Builder = new StringBuilder();

    }
    public async Task<string> ConvertToTextAsync(
        string FilePath,
        string Language,
        string WordDocName) {


        //Configure speech service

        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription
            (ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_KEY,
            ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_REGION);

        config.EnableDictation();

        config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = Language;

        //Configure speech recognition

        var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput
            (FilePath);

        {

            using var speechRecognizer =
                new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

            speechRecognizer.Recognized += (sender, e) => {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                    foreach (var c in e.Result.Text) {
                        Letters.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            };

            speechRecognizer.SessionStarted += (sender, e) => {

                Debug.WriteLine("------> Started");
            };

            speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (sender, e) => {

                Debug.WriteLine("Stop");

                foreach (var item in Letters) {
                    Builder.Append(item);
                }
            };
            speechRecognizer.Recognizing += (sender, e) => {

                Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
                stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
            };

            await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

            // Waits for completion. Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
            await Task.WhenAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });

            return Builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Update

I tried to change the code to this

```
   private TaskCompletionSource<string>? SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource { get; set; }
        private StringBuilder? RecognizedSpeechTextBuilder { get; set; } = new StringBuilder();
        private SpeechRecognizer? SpeechRecognizer { get; set; }

        public async Task<string> ConvertToTextAsync(string filePath,
          string language,
          string wordDocName) {
            // Configure speech service
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_KEY, ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_REGION);
            config.EnableDictation();
            config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = language;

            // Configure speech recognition
            this.SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(filePath);
            using (SpeechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig)) {
                SpeechRecognizer.SessionStarted += OnSessionStarted!;
                SpeechRecognizer.SessionStopped += OnSessionStopped!;
                SpeechRecognizer.Recognizing += OnRecognizing!;
                SpeechRecognizer.Recognized += OnRecognized!;

                await this.SpeechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

                // Wait for the 'SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync' call 
                // before returning the result string.
                // In this case, 'SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync' 
                // is called from a Button.Click event handler.
                return await SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource.Task;
            }
        }

        // Stop speech recognition when the user clicks a button
        private async void OnStopButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            await SpeechRecognizer!.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
        }

        private void OnSessionStarted(object sender, SessionEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine("------> Started");
        }

        private void OnSessionStopped(object sender, SessionEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Stop");

            SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource!.TrySetResult(RecognizedSpeechTextBuilder!.ToString());
        }

        private void OnRecognizing(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        }

        private void OnRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Result.Reason != ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var speechText in e.Result.Text) {
                this.RecognizedSpeechTextBuilder!.Append(speechText);
            }
        }
    }
}

and then I call this method in here'
```

private async void StartAction(object obj) {

```
        IsBusy = true;
        CanShow = Visibility.Visible;

        var FileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
            (FilePath);

        var AudioPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder(ConstantsHelpers.AUDIO);

        var DocumentPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder();

        var AudioFileNamePath = Path.Combine(AudioPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.WAV}");

        var ConvertedAudioPath = AudioHelper.Converter(FilePath!, AudioFileNamePath);

        var DocumentName = Path.Combine(DocumentPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.DOCX}");

        var res = await AzureTranscription.ConvertToTextAsync(ConvertedAudioPath,
                        SelectedItem, DocumentName);

        IsBusy = false;
        StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        CanShow = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
```

```
Update

I manage to get it working, but I need to return the text to my MainViewModel
```

public async Task ConvertToTextAsync(string FilePath, string FileName) {

```
        List<char> Characers = new();

        StringBuilder builder = new();

        //Configure speech service

        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription
            (ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_KEY, ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_REGION);

        config.EnableDictation();

        //Configure speech recognition

        var taskCompleteionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(FilePath);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName)) {
            using var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

            speechRecognizer.Recognized += (sender, e) => {
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                    foreach (var item in e.Result.Text) {
                        Characers.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            };

            speechRecognizer.SessionStarted += (sender, e) => {

                Debug.WriteLine("--------> started");

            };

            speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (sender, e) => {

                Debug.WriteLine("-----------> stooped");

                foreach (var item in Characers) {
                    builder.Append(item);
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
            };

            await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            Task.WaitAny(new[] { taskCompleteionSource.Task });

            await speechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: First, you are using the TaskCompletionSource wrong. It must be of type TaskCompletionSource<string>. The return the TaskCompletionSource.Task directly (remove the Task.WhenAny). Then call TrySetResult with the Builder.ToString.

Comment: I doubt you are using the API correctly. Are you sure you are supposed to mix async API and event based API?

Comment: Do you get any error message or does the Result object provides some info? Is the Recognizing handler called?

Comment: You must also call stopRecognition.TrySetResult from your SessionStopped event handler. Otherwise you transition the TaskCompletionSource prematurely into the completed state.

Comment: No is nos providing any errors, is stange

Comment: Is the input (wav file) valid?

Comment: yes I did some corrections

Comment: It looks like your method returns prematurely. Leaving the `using` scope probably will lead to stop the SpeechRecognizer. I will post a fixed code of yours you can test.

Comment: Do you think is the using? is strange because I use this in another part of the code, and it was working

Comment: What do you mean by remove the task.whenany

Comment: If you have implemented my example. you should be able to remove the `StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` line as it is already called from the `IsBusy` property setter.

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you are returning from the `ConvertToTextAsync` method prematurely. This is because you are transitioning the `TaskCompletionSource` too early. As a consequence you leave the method and therefore the `using` scope of the `SpeechRecognizer`, which as a result will stop the continuous speech recognition.

The idea is to complete the `TaskCompletionSource` not before the `SpeechRecognizer` has stopped (by calling the `SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync` method). You can achieve this by calling `TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult` from the `SpeechRecognizer.SessionStopped` event handler:

```cs
private TaskCompletionSource<string> SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource { get; set; }
private StringBuilder RecognizedSpeechTextBuilder { get; set; }
private SpeechRecognizer SpeechRecognizer { get; set; }

public async Task<string> ConvertToTextAsync(string filePath,
  string language,
  string wordDocName)
{
  if (!File.Exists(filePath))
  {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
  }

  // Configure speech service
  var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_KEY, ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_REGION);
  config.EnableDictation();
  config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = language;

  // Configure speech recognition
  this.SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

  using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(filePath);
  using (this.SpeechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig))
  {
    this.SpeechRecognizer.SessionStarted += OnSessionStarted;
    this.SpeechRecognizer.SessionStopped += OnSessionStopped;
    this.SpeechRecognizer.Recognizing += OnRecognizing;
    this.SpeechRecognizer.Recognized += OnRecognized;
    this.SpeechRecognizer.Recognized += OnCanceled;

    await this.SpeechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

    // Wait for the 'SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync' call 
    // before returning the result string.
    // In this case, 'SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync' 
    // is called from a Button.Click event handler.
    return await this.SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource.Task;
  }
}

// Stop speech recognition when the user clicks a button
private async void OnStopButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await this.SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
}

private void OnSessionStarted(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("------> Started");
}

private void OnSessionStopped(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Stop");

  this.SpeechRecognitionCompletionSource.TrySetResult(this.RecognizedSpeechTextBuilder.ToString());
}

private void OnRecognizing(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
}

private void OnRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Result.Reason != ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
  {
    return;
  }

  foreach (string speechText in e.Result.Text)
  {
    this.RecognizedSpeechTextBuilder.Append(speechText);
  }
}

private void OnCanceled(object sender, SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Reason == CancellationReason.EndOfStream)  
  {
    await this.SpeechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: It keeps not returning anything, I will update

Comment: Make sure `StopContinuousRecognitionAsync` is called at some point in your application.

Comment: Where do you think I should call StopContinuousRecognitionAsync

Comment: From the Button.Click event handler that is meant to cancel the speech recognition.

Comment: In the above example the event handler is named `OnStopButtonClicked`

Comment: This is sill stoppin inmidieltly 

------> Started
Stop

So it won't do anything

Comment: It stops before you click the button? Is there any other place you call `StopContinuousRecognitionAsync `?

Comment: At least you must now get a result.

Comment: yes, I get a "", but I don't want to put a button to call the stop, it should stop when it finishes like this https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/january/mp3-to-text-using-azure-cognitive-services/

Comment: I have updated the example to a file path check in case the specified file does not exist, the code will throw an exception. Maybe your file path is wrong.

Comment: You must call `StopContinuousRecognitionAsync` explicitly. Otherwise it will execute nonstop.

Comment: and for some reason that code works

Comment: What if I want to call it when it completes the file

Comment: what code works?

Comment: https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/january/mp3-to-text-using-azure-cognitive-services/

Comment: and our code do not even call 

 private void OnRecognizing(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        }

Comment: I am out of Ideas. I was working on this app, and it was working fine, the only thing I did was move the code to a method and got fucked up

Comment: I have updated the example to support cancellation once the end of file has been reached. You do this by handling the Canceled event.

Comment: Please copy the full latest version.

Comment: Also ensure that your subscription is valid and the configuration is correct in general.

Comment: Well I just copied and pasted my old code, that was working, but is not working

Comment: I knew it was not related to the latest version. What was the reason?

Comment: For some reason, if you pass the path, you also need the filename without the extension. This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I just put in this and bam working

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName)) {
                using var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

                speechRecognizer.Recognized += (sender, e) => {
                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                        foreach (var item in e.Result.Text) {
                            Characers.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                };

Comment: But I need your help in returning this string

Comment: Let me open another question for this

Comment: But your posted code was not handling the TaskCompletionSource correctly. You were cancelling the Task from the Recognized event which was cancelling your session too early (as stated in my answer). i hope you don't remove those fixes.

Comment: I'm afk. Will look into your new question later.

Comment: Yes do not worry, I will play some Yakuza Kiwame

Comment: This is the new question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74167533/16878827